# NSAttributedString to NSString UTF-8

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, uitextview

My code is something like:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[textView textStorage]];
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[xml appendFormat:@">%@", text];
```

If I have NSASCIIStringEncoding string is ok. When I change NSASCIIStringEncoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding it returns null.But I need UTF-8 because my XML file where I'm appending the string is in UTF-8. Any way how to do that? Thx for reply.

Comment: And it's obviously that I have NSTextView, which is source of textStorage

Comment: Maybe `UITextView`? You tagged your question `iOS` and `NSTextView` at the same time...

Comment: My bad... but then I'm loading xml file on iOS in UITextView :)

Comment: the code is for NStextView and doesnt work at all on ios

Comment: you archive the data and try to get back the resulting bytes as a string.. if the data is binary, this fails... it isn't utf8 data

Comment: Is there any way how I could do that?

Comment: And there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237376/how-to-convert-formatted-content-of-nstextview-to-string is how to do that, but you are saying that doesnt work, so? Btw thx for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `textView` is a UITextView, and xml is a NSMutableString, you should be able to replace that code with:

```
[xml appendString: textView.text];
```

or if you need that `>` prefix:

```
[xml appendFormat:@">%@", textView.text];
```

NSString will keep track of the encodings. You only need to worry about the encoding later when you do something with `xml` (store it or send it through some web service). And then you can simply use `xml.UTF8String` to get a regular C-string in UTF8 format.